# Objective - C: Combine multiple string arrays

Tags: objective-c, ios, arrays, string

I have multiple NSString Arrays that I would like to combine into a single array based on user preferences.

The arrays are created:

```
static const NSString *string1[] = 
{...};

static const NSString *string2[] =
{...};

static NSMutableString *string3[] =
{

};
```

String3 is the holding array where all of the user's choices are added. There are 8 different strings that could be toggled on or off, so a fair number of possible combinations. I've tried a number of things with no success. For example:

```
*string3=[string3 arrayByAddingObjectsInArray:string 2];
```

That gives warnings:

`Instance method '-arrayByAddingObjectsInArry:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')`

and

`Receiver type 'NSMutableString **' is not 'id' or interface pointer, consider casting it to 'id'`

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your basic problem is that you're confusing two different things called "arrays." What you have there are C arrays — they're not objects, so you can't send messages (such as `arrayByAddingObjectsInArray:`) to them. What you *want* is an NSArray.

Declare them all as `NSArray *strings1, *strings2, *strings3`, and then write some method to initialize them like so:

```
+ (id)createArrays {
    strings1 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Something", @"Something else", nil];
    strings2 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Yet another thing", nil];
    strings3 = [[strings1 arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:strings2] retain];
}
```

You'll want to make sure you manage your memory correctly here or you'll leak like crazy. It's usually better to have objects belong to some class, so you can use setters than manage memory for you, rather than store them in global or static variables.

Answer (score 1):

Ummmmm try this code instead

```
NSArray *array1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Wow", @" that", nil];
NSArray *array2 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@" is", @" really", nil];
NSArray *array3 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@" terrible", @" code", nil];

NSArray *fullArray = [array1 arrayByAddingObjectsInArray:[array2 arrayByAddingObjectsInArray:array3]];

NSLog(@"%@", fullArray);
```

The problem you have above is because you are trying to use `arrayByAddingObjectsInArray:` on a class that doesn't have that method defined. `NSArray` is the class with that method, so you need an instance of `NSArray` to use `arrayByAddingObjectsInArray` like the code above.

Answer (score 0):

`NSString`is not an array, there is a terminology issue.

`NSString`s are objects so to create a NSString from static text:

```
NSString *string1 = @"the text";
```

To combine strings use a method found under NSString.

To add a string to string 3 (which is an NSMutableString):

```
[string3 appendString: string2];
```

"Instance method `-arrayByAddingObjectsInArry:` not found" means that there is no method named `-arrayByAddingObjectsInArry:` as part of the `NSString` class since that is the class instance you are sending the message to. (Yes there is a type but that is not the problem).

Consider browsing the `NSString` documentation in the Xcode Organizer window Documentation tab.

Answer (score 0):

You are using C array that holds NSString objects. The idea is:

```
*string3 = malloc(sizeof(NSString*) * count); // Array of count strings
string3[0] = string1[0]; // Put on at index 0
NSLog(@"%@", string1[0]); // Log string at index 0
```

"count" is the sum of "string1" plus "string2".

You can do a for loop with this.